# The mean of probability distribution with pdf given by $x^{-2}$ for $x>1$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose a continuous random variable has a probability density function given by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ for all $x > 1$ and $0$ otherwise.

This is a valid pdf since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx = 1$.

My question is, what is the mean and standard deviation of this distribution?

If I try to calculate

$$\mu=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\,dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\,dx = \infty$$

The calculation of standard deviation requires the value of $E(X^2)$ which also similarly diverges.
Am I doing this correct or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Your density simply has no [moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics))s.

Comment: Yes, $E(X)=\infty$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ does not exist. Your distribution is this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonySaint-Criq

Comment: Thanks @StubbornAtom